# How to create a circle using the simpleGUI module

Tags: python, simplegui

I am trying to create a house using the simpleGUI module in python and want the sun to be in the background of it. However, I don't know how to make a circle to make the shape of the sun. Would I be able to use the cavas.draw_polygon function to do this and if so how? I am not able to use a different module to call functions from.

I honestly have no idea where to start since I currently only know how to make things with straight edges. So far this is my code for the house and I was just going to add the sun part onto the end of what I already have.

```
import simplegui

def draw_handler(canvas):
    canvas.draw_polygon([(100,400),(300,400),(300, 200),(100,200)], 3, "black", "wheat")
    canvas.draw_polygon([(200, 50),(75,200),(325,200)], 3, "black", "red")
    canvas.draw_polygon([(175, 400),(225, 400),(225, 325),(175,325)], 3, "black", "brown")
    canvas.draw_polygon([(175, 280),(175, 230),(125,230),(125,280)], 8, "brown")
    canvas.draw_polygon([(225, 280),(225, 230),(275,230),(275,280)], 8, "brown")
    canvas.draw_line((250,230),(250,280), 8, "brown")
    canvas.draw_line((225,255),(275,255), 8, "brown")
    canvas.draw_line((150,230),(150,280), 8, "brown")
    canvas.draw_line((125,255),(175,255), 8, "brown")
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home Sweet Home", 400, 400)
frame.set_canvas_background("lightblue")
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.start()
```

I'm aware my code could be better, but I am happy with how it is currently and only want the sun to be in the top left corner.

Comment: SimpleGUI's `Canvas` has `.draw_circle()` and various other drawing commands in addition to the `.draw_polygon()` and `.draw_line()` that you're already using - did you not look at the documentation to see what's available?

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for the help, and no I wasn't able to look at that. I tried just looking up all of the functions that it has but couldn't really find anything answering my question. Would you know where to find that documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the official documentation of the `canvas.draw_circle()` method:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#draw_circle

```py
canvas.draw_circle(center_point, radius, line_width, line_color)
canvas.draw_circle(center_point, radius, line_width, line_color, fill_color = color)
```

It is available from **CodeSkulptor3**:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/

It is easy to share your code like this:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user308_2T7LRsAhlB2tIqK.py

You can also see the documentation of my package **SimpleGUICS2Pygame**, that implements all (and more) the **SimpleGUI** module:
https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpleguics2pygame/canvas.html#SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame.canvas.Canvas.draw_circle